# why $\int\frac{dx}{2\sqrt x +2x} = \ln(1+\sqrt x)$+C

Tags: integration

I don't know why $\int\frac{dx}{2\sqrt x +2x} = \ln(1+\sqrt x)$+C .The maple solve that like this : $$\int\frac{dx}{2\sqrt x +2x}:$$ $$=\int\frac{du}{u+1}$$ $$=\int\frac{du_1}{u_1}$$ $$=ln(u_1)$$ $$=ln(u+1)$$ $$=ln(\sqrt x +1)$$ but this is not clear.What is another solution for solving this integration?

Comment: Why is the solution not clear to you?

Comment: No, one $u$ and one $u_1$. Just replace all $u_1$ with $s$ if you want.

Comment: The change of variables: $u=\sqrt x$ and $u_1=u+1$.

Comment: It is an integration by substitution (twice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard answer is: by definition (or by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus if your definitions are set up that way).

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} \ln(1+\sqrt{x}) = \dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}} \times \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}} = \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{x} + 2 x}$$

Therefore, by definition of "indefinite integral" (or by the FTC if your definitions are set up that way), $$\ln(1+\sqrt{x}) = \int \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{x} + 2x} dx$$

Comment: Is that really the FTC, or just the definition of primitive function?

Comment: That's the definition of the antiderivative. And it doesn't explain the solution.

Comment: @mickep I think this depends on your definitions. I'll edit that in.

Comment: @CarlHeckman OP didn't ask for the solution to be explained, but for "another solution".

Comment: @ Patrick Stevens: The student's English is very broken. I'm not sure that's what Soroush meant. Usually, the presence of that sequence of integrals as accompanied by the question: "What is going on here?" ... That is probably part of the reason why the question is on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Just put , $z=\sqrt x+1$. Then it is clear..

Then , $\int \frac{\,dx}{2\sqrt x+2x}=\int \frac{\,dz}{z}=\log (z)+C=\log(\sqrt x+1)+C.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}+2x}dx\;,$$ Let $x=t^2\;,$ Then $dx = 2tdt$

So $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2t}{t+t^2}dt = \int\frac{1}{1+t}dt = \ln|1+t|+\mathcal{C}$$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \ln|1+\sqrt{x}|+\mathcal{C}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\int_{x} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}+2x} = \int_{x}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}(1 + \sqrt{x})} = \int_{x}\frac{D\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}} = \int_{x}\frac{D(1 + \sqrt{x})}{1 + \sqrt{x}} = \log(1+\sqrt{x}) + \text{some constant}.
$$